# How to remove uppercase characters from the end of a string when they are preceded by a lowercase character?

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm scraping some data on college basketball teams from ESPN's BPI page (http://www.espn.com/mens-college-basketball/bpi/_/view/resume) to store in a pandas dataframe. When I read the html table into a dataframe, the abbreviated school name is appended to the full school name. E.g I have several strings that looks like this: "North CarolinaUNC".

How can I remove the UNC from the end of the string? I tried the below regex to match characters at the end of strings:

```
name = "North CarolinaUNC"
name = re.sub(r"\z[A-Z]","", name)
```

but it won't work for schools whose names are made up of two words. Is there a way to write a rule that removes uppercase characters from a string when they are preceded by a lowercase character?

Comment: Unfortunately,  the `\z` anchor doesn't exist in the python regex flavour, you need to use `$` to match ever the end of the string or the end of the line *( depending if the `m` modifier is switched on or off)*.

Comment: In Python, `\Z` matches the very end of the string. However, `$` is enough here, but should be placed on the right, and `[A-Z]` should be `+` quantified. See answers below

Comment: @Kaushik your title doesn't match your "Is there a way to write a rule that removes uppercase characters from a string when they are preceded by a lowercase character?". Which is it? I think you don't want to remove "UNC" from "Foo UNC" for instance. right?

Comment: Right. Though you've already answered the question I just updated the title for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$` to match the end of the string, and non-matching lookbehind to check if the uppercase letters come after lowercase letters:

```
import re
name = "North CarolinaUNC"
name = re.sub(r"(?<=[a-z])[A-Z]+$","", name)
```

results in `North Carolina` all right.

And with that expression, `"North Carolina UNC"` stays unmodified because the uppercase letters, even if at the end of the string, do not come after a lowercase letter.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte done. I thought the lookahead worked in my tests. You have great power of remote hypnosis I guess :)

Comment: *"With great powers comes great responsabilities"*: Ben Parker

Comment: Thanks! Is there any difference to using this one over Willem's answer? If I am using the `+$` anchor, I guess I wouldn't need to check if the preceding character was lowercase, would I?

Comment: Willem (now deleted) answer just removes the uppercase characters at the end of the string. No further checks are done. For instance, it will turn "UCLA" to empty string... (sorry, I'm not an expert in US schools, trying my best :))